# Simplify SQL deletion query

Tags: sql-server

I have an AuditAnswersTable which contains the answers to audit questions, and it has the id of the entry from the AuditTable that the question related to.

I now want to delete all audits where there are no answers provided.  I have this working query, but I'm feeling like there has to be an easier way?

```sql
DELETE FROM AuditTable
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT id FROM AuditTable
    WHERE id NOT IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT audit_id
        FROM AuditAnswersTable
    )
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid the sub-select with a LEFT JOIN:

```
DELETE a
FROM AuditTable a
    LEFT JOIN AuditAnswersTable t
        ON a.id = t.audit_id
WHERE t.audit_id IS NULL ;
```

Comment: Thats much better!

Comment: Yeah, the "left join - where null" changed my life once I finally got my head around it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

```
DELETE FROM AuditTable
WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT audit_id
    FROM AuditAnswersTable
)
```

Comment: Chuckle.  So obvious once I see it.  Thanks.

Comment: Thought it might be one of those :)

Comment: The DISTINCT isn't necessary, by the way, and might hurt performance by inducing a sort.  It's been a few years since I've used SQL Sever, but at the time existential quantification was faster without DISTINCT.   You may want to experiment.